# QGIS add +1 to field value where fid is biggest

Tags: qgis

In my new feature(new) I want to have a field("Number") where the value is the one from another feature(X) + 1. Where feature(X) is chosen based on the biggest "fid" value.

Simply saying, QGIS should look up for the feature where "fid" is the biggest, take the value of the field("Number"), add 1 and write the value in the new feature.

| fid | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 3 | 25 |
| 4 | 26 |
| 5 | 27 |
| 6 | 15 |
| 7 | 16 |

the field "Number" is a field that can be changed manually. But when it isn't changed manually it autofills with the value of the last line (so the line where "fid" is the biggest) and adds 1.

In my case they won't be a NULL entry.
Let me explain the workflow I try to reach, maybe it's going to be clearer:

- I'm using a device which records sounds. Each recording is giving a number automatically by the device. The first recording on my device has the number 001 the second the number 002 and so on.
- In QGIS I want to set a point for every location where I make a sound recording. But I don't want to fill in every number of my recording manually everytime. I should only set the very first recording.

My first idea was to use the function `lpad(maximum("Number") +1, 3,0)`. This works fine until the moment when I have to change the recording device or the memory card. In this case my recording device will start counting from scratch (001, 002, 003 and so on). The `lpad(maximum(''Number'') +1, 3,0)` is not suited for this case because it will look up the biggest "Number" and not the last in the table.

So I need a function where it is possible to look for the last added value.
I really hope it's clearer now.

Comment: When you create a new feature, you want to autofill a field?

Comment: Your post is confusing because it appears that your are mixing the terms "feature" and "field".  When you use "feature" do you really mean "field"?

Comment: Yes the field should be autofilled.

Comment: i edited my post with a table. Hope it's more understandable. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfotunately, Jonas, it is still confusing, including your image. Numerous people here would like to help you, so please edit your post to show *exactly* what you would like to achieve.

Comment: What should happen if the feature with the largest `fid` has a `NULL` entry for `number`?

Comment: Your explanation certainly makes things much clearer.